Fuzz testing with system program
When fuzz testing outside of bpf-land (i.e. the target os is not solana), cpis will fall back to crate-level program stubs, and we can invoke spl token instructions with the handy processor:
pub struct TestSyscallStubs {
    pub unix_timestamp: Option<i64>,
}

impl program_stubs::SyscallStubs for TestSyscallStubs {
    fn sol_invoke_signed(
        &self,
        instruction: &Instruction,
        account_infos: &[AccountInfo],
        signers_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]],
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let mut new_account_infos = vec![];
        // Fill ix account metas as needed...

        if instruction.program_id == spl_token::ID {
            spl_token::processor::Processor::process(
                &instruction.program_id,
                &new_account_infos,
                &instruction.data,
            )
        } else if instruction.program_id == system_program::ID {
            // TODO
        }
  }
}

How can we do the same kind of thing for system program instructions like a SOL transfer?

There's no simple way unfortunately. The system program's instruction processor is written with native program hooks like the invoke context: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/27f4b3d3b9b2cfad274c9cb45c33ea9a4009acb0/programs/system/src/system_processor.rs#L301
You might just need to stub the instruction processor for the few functions that you care about, ie:
if instruction.program_id == system_program::ID {
    let instruction = limited_deserialize(instruction.data)?;
    match instruction {
        SystemInstruction::CreateAccount => { ... }
        SystemInstruction::Transfer => { ... }
        _ => // error for ones that you don't care about
    }
}

Once there's a BPF version of the system program, this will be much easier, but it isn't done just yet.
